# Why doesn't IntelliJ recognize viewBox attribute of svg element?

Tags: html, svg, intellij-idea, attributes

My IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) doesn't recognize `viewBox` attribute of `svg` elements:

[image]

I thought it had something to do with the fact that this attribute is also not found anywhere in [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_attributes.asp) website.

Comment: This article by Sara Soueidan [Understanding SVG Coordinate Systems and Transformations (Part 1) — The viewport, viewBox, and preserveAspectRatio](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is already tracked [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31136) and is fixed in the 2018.2 version of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

w3schools has something about it on [here](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_reference.asp) search for <svg> *viewBox="the points "seen" in this SVG drawing area. 4 values separated by white space or commas. (min x, min y, width, height)"* in ide you must provide a valid dtd some versions may not have all definitions.

You may also try to add namespace to svg element `<svg ... xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`